# How to use specific bundler version inside bash shell script

Tags: ruby-on-rails, bash, bundler

I'm running some bundle install and rake migrations inside a bash script, but the bundle version used is not the one I need. How can I make it use a different bundle version

```
#!/bin/bash

function run_setup {
    echo "Running setup and DB migrations"
    cd $cwd/apps/rails_app
    gem install bundler -v 1.3
    bundle -v                      # SHOWS version 1.15
    bundle install                 # Errors out
    rake db:migrate
}
```

When I run the bash function above, bash uses bundle version 1.15. I need it to use the 1.3 version it is installing before calling bundle install. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can pass the version to bundler command like this:

```
bundle _X.X.X_ install
```

So your function would look something like this:

```
#!/bin/bash

function run_setup {
    echo "Running setup and DB migrations"
    cd $cwd/apps/rails_app
    gem install bundler -v 1.3
    bundle _1.3_ install
    rake db:migrate
}
```

Comment: I did try this before, but had other issues such as ruby version and using rvm inside bash script is not just trivial. But your answer is indeed how you select a specific bundler version.